# A loop exits prematurely when using StreamReader

Tags: vb.net, winforms

It's been a long time since I've programmed. I'm writing a form in VB.NET, and using StreamReader to read a text file and populate an 2D array. Here is the text file:

```
あかさたなはまやらわん
いきしちにひみ　り
うくすつぬふむゆる
えけせてねへめ　れ
おこそとのほもよろを
```

And here is the loop, which is within the Load event.

```
Dim Line As String
Dim Row As Integer = 0
Using sReader As New IO.StreamReader("KanaTable.txt")

    Do
        Line = sReader.ReadLine
        For i = 0 To Line.Length - 1
            KanaTable(Row, i) = Line(i)
        Next
        Row += 1
    Loop Until sReader.EndOfStream

End Using
```

The problem is, once the i in the For Loop reaches 10, it completes the loop and skips the other lines, even when I have a breakpoint. Can you let me know what's probably going on here?

Comment: Could you explain what are doing with each single charater (Line(i)) in that `KanaTable(Row, i)`

Comment: And after that is your Form Showing up?

Comment: You mentioned this is in Form.Load.  If you are running on a 64 bit computer then any exceptions in .Load will be hidden and the sub will just exit.  This link will show you how to temporarily break on all exceptions to try and debug your problem. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx

Comment: That's really useful to know @Bradley. I'll try debugging when I get a chance and get back to you.

Comment: You should not be doing IO in your Form Load method, do it in a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @DourHighArch Well firstly, this is a prototype, I didn't intend to *keep* the IO in the Form load (it now has a subroutine.) But also, this is only a personal project code; if it works, I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem, it was very simple. The array declaration for KanaTable:

```
Dim KanaTable(4, 9) As Char
```

should have been

```
Dim KanaTable(4, 10) As Char
```

Because there was one less space in the array than there should have been, the debugger must have been throwing an IndexOutOfRange which I couldn't see, because, stupid Windows bug (thanks to Bradley Uffner for pointing out this bug.)

Comment: The debugger wasn't throwing the exception - your code was throwing the exception.

Comment: And it's not a windows bug. It was a bug in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a PEBCAK, I'm not blaming Windows for everything. By "stupid windows bug" I mean the VS bug that means the debugger doesn't throw exceptions when in the Form Load event on 64 bit windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an array of arrays or a list of arrays (`List(Of Char())`), you can get this down to a single line of code:

```
Dim KanaTable()() As Char = IO.File.ReadLines("KanaTable.txt").Select(Function(line) line.ToCharArray()).ToArray()
```

If that's too complicated for you, we can at least simplify the existing code:

```
Dim KanaTable As New List(Of Char())
Dim Line As String
Using sReader As New IO.StreamReader("KanaTable.txt")

    Line = sReader.ReadLine()
    While Line IsNot Nothing 
        KanaTable.Add(Line.ToCharArray())
        Line = sReader.ReadLine()
    End While

End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't see an error immediately, but you could try to adapt your code to this:

```
Using reader As New IO.StreamReader("KanaTable.txt")
    Do
        line= reader.ReadLine()
        If line = Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        For i = 0 To Line.Length - 1
            KanaTable(Row, i) = Line(i)
        Next
        Row += 1

    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Doesn't address the error, but it gives a (potentially) viable alternative solution.